# How to get the text next to my checkbox inline, and next to checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a web page in which I need the text associated with each text to be next to the checkbox. Currently, this is what it looks like:

[image: Text underneath checkboxes]

I do not want any of the checkboxes or labels associated with them to be centered. I want them to be aligned to the left. Here are my JavaScript & global style code:

JS:

```
import React from 'react'

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Form } from '../../global styles/index';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

function ArtistForm(){

    const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
    console.log(errors);
    
    return(
        <div>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <div className="form-container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="column">
                            <label>First Name:</label> 
                            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="FirstName" ref={register({required: true, max: 30, min: 2})} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="column">
                            <label>Last Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="LastName" ref={register({max: 30, min: 2})} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
            
                    <div>
                        <label>Medium:</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id= "designillustration" name="medium" /><span>Design & Illustration</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="digitalart" name="medium" /><span>Digital Art</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="drawing" name="medium" /><span>Drawing</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="paintingmixedmedia" name="medium" /><span>Painting & Mixed Media</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="photography" name="medium" /><span>Photography</span>
                    </div>


                    <div>
                        <label>Artist Bio:  </label>
                        <textarea placeholder="Bio" name="Bio" ref={register({required: true, maxLength: 500})} />
                    </div>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ArtistForm
```

Global Style for Form Component:

```
// form styling
export const Form = styled.form`
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    label {
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 15px;
        text-indent: -15px;
    }

    input {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin-top: 10px; 
        display: block;
    }

    textarea {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .form-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 90%;
        padding: 20px;
        
        @media(max-width: 500px){
            padding: 20px 50px 50px;
        }
    }

    div {
        display: inline-block, flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding: .2rem;
    }

    p {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .instructions{
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .column {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 10px;
    }


    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
`
```

Is there something with the input tag that is interfering with how the checkboxes show up with the labels for them? I have tried over and over again to use `display: inline-block` but for some reason I cannot get the text to be inline with the checkbox. I have also tried to align the text to the left for the label but did not have any luck.

Comment: use `display: flex; align-items: center;`

Comment: Not sure where'd you get your CSS from,  but `display: inline-block, flex` is not a valid CSS. Display values are not comma-separated, in fact there are no multiple values for `display`.

Comment: For you input styles, remove ```display: block```. The natural display for an input is ```inline-block``` which is what you would need for the behavior your looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, the solution can be done in 3 steps:

1. **removing** the following styles from the `input` selector

   ```
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
   ```

   Both of these styles were giving your input element the width: 100% which pushes the text below.
2. Then from there, what I would do is wrap each of the `input` and `span` pairs in divs. This will section off the two inline elements into its own container while allocating the full width to the elements e.g.

   ```
   <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id= "designillustration" name="medium" />
      <span>Design & Illustration</span>
   </div>
   ```
3. Add the following css to restore width: 100% on the text inputs

   ```
   input[type="text"] {
        width: 100%;
   }
   ```

Here is a codepen that demonstrates the solution on the first checkbox input row: https://codepen.io/ariellav/pen/poyvPKR

**Other note:**

Replacing

```
label {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
}
```

with

```
label {
    display: block;
}
```

should reap the same result

Answer (score 2):

you've set your

```
input{
width: 100%;
}
```

that takes the whole width of the container and doesn't allow the text to display inline

Comment: display: block; also makes the element take the whole width of the container

Answer (score 1):

You have to have `label` tags next that are to/for the input button. Also, you must get rid of your `input{width: 100%;}`

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="designillustration" name="medium"/>
<label for="designillustration">Design & Illustration</label>
```